# Android OpenGl What is a stride?

Tags: android, graphics, opengl-es

I am studying opengl.

I came acroos a function such as drawXXXXXXX in which one of the parameeters is stride...

I don't knowits usage and don't know the meaning of strides also.

Could anyoe tell me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you want to pass more information to a vertex shader than only the position of the vertices, you can use what is called interwinded array. For example:

```
struct Information {
    GLfloat position[3];
    GLfloat color[3];
    GLfloat texture[2];
};
```

So, one possible instantiation of this structure is:

```
struct Information vertices[] = { 
   // Positions          // Colors           // Texture Coords
   {{0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f},   {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f},   {1.0f, 1.0f}},
   {{0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f},   {0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f},   {1.0f, 0.0f}},
   {{-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f},   {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f},   {0.0f, 0.0f}},
   {{-0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f},   {1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f},   {0.0f, 1.0f}}
};
```

In order to pass this correctly to a shader attribute, you need to inform it exactly how to extract, for example, the position information. This is where stride come in place.

Stride is the amount of bytes that you need to jump to start a new index on this array. In this case it is `sizeof(struct Information)`. The picture below helps

[image]

For more information look at the [learnopengl](http://www.learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Textures) tutorials

Comment: This answer is much more clear than the accepted answer, the picture explains clearly what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

Stride allows a vertex array to access its desired data at regular intervals in the array. For example, to reference only the color values in the intertwined array, the following call starts from the beginning of the array (which could also be passed as &intertwined[0]) and jumps ahead 6 * sizeof(GLfloat) bytes, which is the size of both the color and vertex coordinate values. This jump is enough to get to the beginning of the data for the next vertex.

glColorPointer (3, GL_FLOAT, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), intertwined);

You can follow the following links----

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa473780(v=vs.85).aspx

http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter02.html

Comment: Could me give me some example with brief explanation?